# jQuery .each() .find()を用いた特定要素、属性値取得について

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

jQueryを用いて、以下HTMLより
「hoge1hoge1_2 数量：1 , hoge2hoge2_2 数量：2 , hoge3hoge3_2 数量：3 ...」と
class="boxlist_"内にあるclass="list_"分だけ繰り返しで、
特定属性のみピックアップし文字列が連結されreturn値を返したい次第です。

なお、数量についてはselect内で
selected要素を持つもののみ、値として取得したいです。

▼HTML

```
<table class="boxlist_">
<tbody>
    <tr class="list_">
        <td class="name_">
            <div class="name_">

                <div class="name1_"><a href="/hoge/" title="hpge">hoge1</a></div>            
                <span class="name2_">hoge1_2</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="price_box_" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="qty_">数量<br>
            <select name="qty1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4" selected="">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_">
        <td class="name_">
            <div class="name_">
                <div class="name2_"><a href="/hoge/" title="hpge">hoge2</a></div>            
                <span class="name2_">hoge2_2</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="price_box_" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="qty_">数量<br>
            <select name="qty1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2" selected="">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_">
        <td class="name_">
            <div class="name_">
                <div class="name3_"><a href="/hoge/" title="hpge">hoge3</a></div>            
                <span class="name2_">hoge3_2</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="price_box_" nowrap="nowrap">
            <p class="qty_">数量<br>
            <select name="qty1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3" selected="">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

▼試しているjs

```
function(){
    var result = [];
    jQuery(".boxist_ tr.list_").map(function(index, Element){
    var itemName = jQuery(Element).find('td.name_ div.name_').text().replace(/\s+/g, "");
    var itemQty =jQuery(Element).find('p.qty_ select option:selected').attr('value'); 
    result.push(itemName+"数量："+" "+itemQty).join(","); //配列に追加
    return result;
    });
    //console.log(result);
}
```

これですと、[] という値となってしまい、
うまく希望している値が返ってきません。

どう修正すればわからず、お教えいただけますとありがたいです。
何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

最初の間違いは、

```js
    jQuery(".boxist_ tr.list_").map(function(index, Element){
```

`.boxist` → `.boxlist` です。

```js
    result.push(itemName+"数量："+" "+itemQty).join(","); //配列に追加
```

せっかく`map()`なのでコールバックの中で`push()`する必要はありませんし、`join()`するタイミングがおかしいです。

```js
function() {
  let result = jQuery(".boxist_ tr.list_").map(function(index, element){
    let itemName = jQuery(element).find('td.name_ div.name_').text().replace(/\s+/g, "");
    let itemQty = jQuery(element).find('p.qty_ select option:selected').attr('value'); 
    return `${itemName}数量：${itemQty}`;
  }).get().join(",");
  return result;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事解決できました！

Comment: 解決してよかったです。よろしかったら回答を承認してくださいませ。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers